# How to calculate slope of regression line at different intervals on a curve and apply to multiple columns

Tags: r, function, lapply, lm

I want to calculate the slope of the regression line at different intervals on a curve and then apply this across multiple columns in a dataframe a to produce a new dataframe Curve_9.20. Below is a heavily subsetted dataframe and the code I'm using to run the function Curve but it is producing the displayed error.

```
a <- structure(list(RunTime = c(7.043, 7.093, 7.143, 7.193, 7.243, 
7.293, 7.343, 7.393, 7.443, 7.493, 7.543, 7.593, 7.643, 7.693, 
7.743, 7.793, 7.843, 7.893, 7.943, 7.993, 8.043, 8.093, 8.142, 
8.193, 8.243, 8.293, 8.343, 8.393, 8.443, 8.493, 8.543, 8.593, 
8.643, 8.693, 8.743, 8.793, 8.843, 8.893, 8.943, 8.993, 9.043
), O2_229 = c(216.272, 216.006, 216.164, 215.976, 215.937, 216.012, 
216.224, 216.354, 216.584, 216.477, 216.347, 216.538, 216.315, 
216.385, 216.297, 216.363, 216.353, 216.301, 216.379, 216.594, 
216.192, 215.955, 216.134, 216.155, 216.254, 216.316, 216.313, 
216.413, 216.477, 216.225, 216.347, 216.16, 215.976, 216.093, 
216.224, 216.179, 216.239, 216.349, 216.085, 216.089, 216.213
), O2_35 = c(183.962, 184.032, 184.143, 184.134, 183.979, 184.028, 
184.176, 184.055, 184.119, 184.137, 184.094, 184.114, 184.308, 
184.097, 184.2, 184.287, 184.048, 184.263, 184.263, 184.346, 
184.322, 184.256, 184.462, 184.155, 184.246, 184.328, 184.232, 
184.418, 184.379, 184.331, 184.367, 184.298, 184.351, 184.375, 
184.333, 184.351, 184.33, 184.247, 184.388, 184.404, 184.392)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = 142:182)

Curve <- function(y)
{
c(coef(lm(y ~ RunTime, subset(a, RunTime >= 7.043 & RunTime <= 
8.043)))[2], # 10%
coef(lm(y ~ RunTime, subset(a, RunTime >= 9.000 & RunTime <= 
9.043)))[2]) # 20%
}

Curve_9.20 <- data.frame("LightIntensity" = c("10%", "20%"), 
lapply(a[c(2,3)], Curve))


Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ RunTime, data = 
subset(a,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'RunTime')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing `lm` with a `y`variable from the original dataset and a `x` from the subset, thus the error of different lengths. You can solve it by providing `lm` with the column names, so all variables will be called from the subset.
Since the right side of the formula is the same for both cases, the simplest workaround is to pass the whole formula as a single string and in each `lapply` iteration only the `y` will change.

```
a <- structure(list(RunTime = c(7.043, 7.093, 7.143, 7.193, 7.243, 
                                7.293, 7.343, 7.393, 7.443, 7.493, 7.543, 7.593, 7.643, 7.693, 
                                7.743, 7.793, 7.843, 7.893, 7.943, 7.993, 8.043, 8.093, 8.142, 
                                8.193, 8.243, 8.293, 8.343, 8.393, 8.443, 8.493, 8.543, 8.593, 
                                8.643, 8.693, 8.743, 8.793, 8.843, 8.893, 8.943, 8.993, 9.043
), O2_229 = c(216.272, 216.006, 216.164, 215.976, 215.937, 216.012, 
              216.224, 216.354, 216.584, 216.477, 216.347, 216.538, 216.315, 
              216.385, 216.297, 216.363, 216.353, 216.301, 216.379, 216.594, 
              216.192, 215.955, 216.134, 216.155, 216.254, 216.316, 216.313, 
              216.413, 216.477, 216.225, 216.347, 216.16, 215.976, 216.093, 
              216.224, 216.179, 216.239, 216.349, 216.085, 216.089, 216.213
), O2_35 = c(183.962, 184.032, 184.143, 184.134, 183.979, 184.028, 
             184.176, 184.055, 184.119, 184.137, 184.094, 184.114, 184.308, 
             184.097, 184.2, 184.287, 184.048, 184.263, 184.263, 184.346, 
             184.322, 184.256, 184.462, 184.155, 184.246, 184.328, 184.232, 
             184.418, 184.379, 184.331, 184.367, 184.298, 184.351, 184.375, 
             184.333, 184.351, 184.33, 184.247, 184.388, 184.404, 184.392)), class = 
  "data.frame", row.names = 142:182)


Curve <- function(y)
{
  y <- paste0(y, '~ RunTime')
  c(coef(lm(y, subset(a, RunTime >= 7.043 & RunTime <= 
                                  8.043)))[2], # 10%
    coef(lm(y, subset(a, RunTime >= 9.000 & RunTime <= 
                                  9.043)))[2]) # 20%
}

Curve_9.20 <- data.frame("LightIntensity" = c("10%", "20%"), 
                         lapply(names(a[c(2,3)]), Curve))
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. Thanks for the help, this worked great!